# Folder Sync option disabled

Tags: sitecore-rocks

I'm unable to use the Folder Sync functionality in Sitecore Rocks.
(https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks/blob/master/docs/Tools/FolderSynchronization.md)
When I right-click on a VS folder that contains MVC views, "Sitecore >" option is disabled.  How do I enable this functionality?

Setup:

- Visual Studio 2017 (v.15.3.5); running as admin
- Sitecore Rocks Extension is enabled. (v. 2.1.0.79)
- Sitecore menu ->"Turn Features On
  or Off" - all boxes are checked (but 'All' radio button doesn't stay
  selected after OK).
- Sitecore Explorer is working; connected via Hard Rock Service
- Sitecore 8.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably didn't connect your Visual Studio project to the Sitecore instance. You can do this via: right click on your Visual Studio project in the `Solution Explorer -> Sitecore -> Project Properties -> Select a "Sitecore Explorer Connection".`
Then you can click "Test..." to see if your connection works.

**Note**: This is not the same as the connection to your Sitecore instance in the *Sitecore* Explorer.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, although the Test was successful then also it didn't work but then once I Checked `Installed Sitecore Connector` and then test it again

[image]

Then it added three more options and now my All Sitecore-TDS-related options are enabled

[image]

Hope it may help others!!!