# Folder is not listed in the Select File dialog

Tags: sitecore-rocks

While following the setup steps for the Sitecore Rocks folder sync, I do not see the folder I am attempting to sync listed in the Select File dialog.

As you can see in the image below, I am attempting to sync the Scripts folder, but it isn't an option in the Select File dialog.

[image: Trying to sync the Scripts folder]

Comment: Are you connected with the Sitecore Instance? Did you get chance to look at these two questions? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7044/folder-sync-not-working?rq=1 and https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/folder-sync-option-disabled?rq=1

Comment: Can you be more specific with the issue that you are facing?

Comment: @AmitabhVyas I am connected to a Sitecore Instance, & I did look at those two questions before posting.  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @RathanM I am not sure how I can be any more specific.  There is not a Scripts folder in the Select File dialog on the left, but there is one in the project on the right.  That's the folder I am attempting to sync.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The Select File dialog is listing the file/folder structure in the \inetpub\wwwroot\site.name\Website folder.

Therefore, when adding a new folder in the project that you want to sync, you need to add a corresponding folder in the \inetpub\wwwroot\site.name\Website folder.